# How rare are black hole mergers?

Tags: black-holes

I understand that black hole mergers are rare. We see a few per year in a volume billions of light years across. But how rare are they?

[This](https://www.ligo.org/science/Publication-O2BBHPop/index.php) paper infers black hole merger rates from measured black hole mergers. For 10 - 30 solar mass black holes, there are roughly $1 - 3$ mergers per gigaparsec$^3$ per year per solar mass.

We know of a few black holes independent of gravitational wave measurements. Is there any estimate of how many black hole pairs are there in this volume that we could observe if they did collide?

Comment: Just a note that the paper you link to is out of date. Here is a more recent version with many more BBH measurements: https://www.ligo.org/science/Publication-O3aPopulations/